# Запись Id юзер в бд бот Telegram Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, python-telegram-bot

Пытаюсь подключить к боту бд с id юзеров для дальнейшей рассылки сообщений от имени бота
Использовал руководство https://habr.com/ru/post/552788
Пытался адаптировать под aiogram

Возникает ошибка, если написать боту "Раскидки":
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если написать боту "Раскидки"

Бот:

```
#import aiogram
import markups as nav
import sqlite3
import re
from aiogram import types, Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.builtin import CommandStart
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
import asyncio


TOKEN = "..."

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot,storage=storage)
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
cursor = conn.cursor()

def db_table_val(user_id: int, user_name: str, user_surname: str, username: str):
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO test (user_id, user_name, username) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', (user_id, user_name, username))
    conn.commit()

async def on_startup(_):
    arr = []  # абстрактный массив с юзер_айди
    for user_id in arr:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text="Бот запущен!")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)



@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def command_start(message: types.Message):
    user_channel_status = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id='@...', user_id=message.from_user.id)
    if user_channel_status["status"] != 'left':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Привет, {0.first_name} \n...'.format(message.from_user), reply_markup = nav.mainMenu)
    else:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '... ')
    
@dp.message_handler()
async def bot_message(message: types.Message):

    if message.text == '...':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '... ')
    elif message.text == 'Раскидки':
        user_channel_status = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id='@mmi', user_id=message.from_user.id)
        if user_channel_status["status"] != 'left':
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '⬇️...:', reply_markup = nav.mapsMenu)
            await us_id == message.from_user.id
            await db_table_val(user_id==us_id)
            bot.polling(none_stop=True)
        else:
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '...')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates = True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не совсем знакоток в этом, но зачем тебе эта строка?
await us_id == message.from_user.id
Ты можешь просто в БД передавать user_id

```
# import aiogram
import markups as nav
import sqlite3
import re
from aiogram import types, Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.builtin import CommandStart
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
import asyncio

TOKEN = "..."

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
cursor = conn.cursor()


def db_table_val(user_id: int, user_name: str, user_surname: str, username: str):
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO test (user_id, user_name, username) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
                   (user_id, user_name, username))
    conn.commit()


async def on_startup(_):
    arr = []  # абстрактный массив с юзер_айди
    for user_id in arr:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text="Бот запущен!")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def command_start(message: types.Message):
    user_channel_status = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id='@...', user_id=message.from_user.id)
    if user_channel_status["status"] != 'left':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Привет, {0.first_name} \n...'.format(message.from_user),
                               reply_markup=nav.mainMenu)
    else:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '... ')


@dp.message_handler()
async def bot_message(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == '...':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '... ')
    elif message.text == 'Раскидки':
        user_channel_status = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id='@maskovmi', user_id=message.from_user.id)
        if user_channel_status["status"] != 'left':
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '⬇️...:', reply_markup=nav.mapsMenu)
            db_table_val(user_id=message.from_user.id, user_name=message.from_user.username, user_surname=message.from_user.first_name, username='') # Тут я не знаю, зачем тебе 2 username
        else:
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '...')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

И будет лучше, если сохранение в БД делать после нажатия /start. Ибо человек может не писать "Раскидки", и тогда он не попадет в базу

Comment: чуть подправил ваш вариант и заработало, спасибо